# Joint Js : link rendered under the shape

Tags: jointjs

I am creating diagram dynamically.Let's say we have three rectangle shapes Activity1,Activity2 and Activity3 and we connect

Activity1 to Activity2 ,
Activity2 to Activity3 ,
Activity3 to Activity1

here we have a loop back on Activity3 to Activity1
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjPZK.jpg)

Doing so hides the link from Activity3 to Activity1 behind the Activity2

Is there any automatic path creation between shapes or i have to manually describe vertices for lines

Desired Result:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwbwZ.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I just resolved it using

```
router: { name: 'manhattan' }
```

...

```
  var link = new joint.shapes.standard.Link({ connector: { name: 'rounded' }, router: { name: 'manhattan' } });
  link.source(element1);
  link.target(element2);
  link.addTo(graph);
```

...